# Error trying to create a AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, create-react-app, android-virtual-device

I get the following error after I select finish. I attached the image of the Virtual Device Configuration screen. Also, I updated my HAXM to the latest version but Android Studio does not seem to notice.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdInfo.getId()" because the return value of "com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd()" is null
at com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.virtualtab.BuildVirtualDeviceConfigurationWizardActionListener.actionPerformed(BuildVirtualDeviceConfigurationWizardActionListener.java:51)
at com.intellij.util.ui.StatusText$1.onClick(StatusText.java:91)
at com.intellij.ui.ClickListener$1.mouseReleased(ClickListener.java:59)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
at com.intellij.ui.table.JBTable.processMouseEvent(JBTable.java:764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:831)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:753)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

Tried to create a virtual device in Android Studio for development work but got an error. I updated the SDK tool, updated HAXM turned off Hyper-V,